# User unable to open docs from embedded webpart in page

Tags: web-part, permissions, pages

I'm dealing with some unusual (to me) behavior when a special user group is attempting to open documents. The documents are displayed in a web part of a document library embedded in a page with a specific filter enabled (Status='Partner Review').

When documents in the underlying doclib are tagged as 'Partner Review' then they should appear in the webpart on the page. This is happening so no worries.
Another feature that is used is that when the tagging occurs a workflow kicks off in Impersonation Phase and it changes the permissions on the file to allow access to the file to the special user group (Partner Review Team).

The partner review team has special permissions only to see documents that they are permitted to see. The permis are as follows:

1. List Perms

   - Edit items
   - View items
   - Open items
   - View versions
2. Site Perms

   - Browse directories
   - View pages
   - Browser User Info
   - Use Remote Interfaces
   - Use client integration features
   - Open

So, everything is working quite well. The workflow works, changes permission on the document and the webpart in the page is only showing documents tagged with the appropriate status.

Using a test Sharepoint account I can navigate to the page and see everything as I would expect a real user to see it. However, when I click on the file I have no options to open it, edit it or do anything else.

Has anyone experienced this issue or have any recommendations for how to solve it?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was actually an issue with the active directory test user we were using. The test user, while having the exact same permissions as every other user in the group had some other funky configuration *outside* of Sharepoint that was causing the file handlers to malfunction.